# Apollo store clears the data after running the writeQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using apollo-graphql for my project. Recently i faced the problem, i add the site from **addSitesPage** but **SitesPage** does not show the recently added site. So i used the **refetchQueries** which works great and recently added site shows up but as its not an optimistic solution so i tried to update the store after running the mutation, but whenever i update it, it clears all the previously added sites and page shows nothing. But when i refreshes the page all sites show up again. I am sure that there is a problem with my data concatenation logic, here is my mutation which also updates the store

```
this.props.mutate({
    variables : { data : variables},
    update: (store, { data: { Site : { SiteCreate  }  } }) => {
       // Read the data from the cache for this query.
       const data = store.readQuery({query: SitesFetchQuery });
       data.viewer.sites.edges.push(SiteCreate);
       // After executing the below statement store clears all the data
       store.writeQuery({ query: SitesFetchQuery, data });    
     },
  });
```

Mutation Query:

```
mutation SiteSaveMutation($data: JSON!) {
    Site {
        SiteCreate(input: {data: $data}) {
            obj {
                id
                name
                active
                id
                siteTypeId
                ownerId
                location {
                    lat
                    lng
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sites Fetching Query:

```
query SitesFetchQuery {
    viewer {
        sites(where:{active: true}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    name
                    image
                    siteType {
                        id
                        name
                        icon
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```